# Can an ideal diode pair (evaluation board) be used for backing up one battery with another?

Tags: batteries, backup

I'm trying to use 2 ideal diodes [within a MAX40203 evaluation kit] for "OR-ing" two battery power sources... to extend the length of time for driving an outdoor flag light. My understanding was that the battery source with the higher voltage value should "rule". But my setup seems to temporarily make the spotlight brighter, rather than to provide a "switch" for the two battery sources--which is what I intended.  {Each battery source actually consists of two Lithium batteries; each set is charged by its own photovoltaic [PV] module.}

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX40203_W_EVKIT-2006979.pdf

{edit}: I've attached a link to the pdf for the evaluation kit. But as its operation is that of an "ideal diode", I think the kit can be thought of as one input source feeding one diode, the other feeding a second diode, with the far end of the diodes tied--feeding the the output to the load. (i.e. it can be treated as a black box.

I'm asking if what I'm doing is even feasible? **Most of what I've read about using OR-ing for backup power purposes describes using batteries as backups for plug-in (regulated) power supplies, not for "backing up batteries with batteries".**

I also performed tests indoors "on the bench" with a duplicate setup. The type of spotlight used to light the flag consists of 7 LEDs--which ideally should be driven by a constant current source, etc. While I don't know the design internals of each PV/battery unit, it is clear that when tested separately, the output voltage values decrease over time... and the spotlight dims over time. Given the availability of only limited battery power, it is not surprising that there seems to be limited or no provision for regulation.

I did have one or two email exchanges with the company, but I'm not sure I was able to clearly explain what I was trying to get across. {edit}: They suggested the kit will work for my application.

Any insight would be appreciated. I'm doing this as a favor for a friend, and I will be moving out of the area shortly.

{edit}:

When I tested the duplicate setup indoors, I deliberately arranged for the two PV/Battery units to begin with two different states of charge. One was measured at 3.9VDC; the other at 3.5VDC (with no load attached). When the load (i.e. spotlight) was connected, the first unit's voltage value dropped from 3.9VDC to ≈3.1VDC; the second unit's voltage value dropped from 3.5VDC to ≈3.0VDC. What was striking here was that the two units began with fairly distinct voltage values, but once a load was applied the voltage values became quite similar. This perhaps suggests why the evaluation kit might share the power from the 2 sources... rather than pick a winner. Separate bench tests showed that the output current value from the evaluation kit exceeded that contributed by either source alone.

Comment: _"... to **extend the length of time** for driving an outdoor flag light. "_ - if that is what you want then the ideal diodes are doing the job. _"Each battery source actually consists of two Lithium batteries"_ - what type of 'lithium' battery do they have?

Comment: The ideal diodes may be doing "their" job, but they are not doing what I was looking for in the context of extending the LED spotlight nightly on time. The evaluation board seems to be making the spotlight (temporarily) brighter--but not extending the length of time which the spotlight stays lit. While I didn't know if doubling the PV/Battery units would actually double the length of time, I was hoping it would provide some useful improvement. I'm not suggesting the ideal diode isn't working correctly, I'm just noting that it's not doing what I needed.

Comment: Each of the two units I'm using to drive the LED spotlight contains two 3.7V 2000mAh batteries in parallel. They are identified as type 18650. I'm not really surprised by this... LEDs like something akin to a constant-current source. But my bench-testing showed that the two sources were combining to over-drive (e.g. 600-700 mA instead of a few hundred less) the current the LED spotlight should have been getting. My (limited) understanding of the use of the two ideal diodes was that their typical application is to provide back-up when the main (e.g. plugged in supply) source has been lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already observed that the battery voltage drops when it's under load, so think about that for a moment. If the two batteries are at anywhere near a similar state of charge, and you switch the load between them, then the one providing power will always have a lower voltage than the one not providing power. But you have them hooked up to something that tries to enforce the condition that the one with the higher voltage is always providing power.

So how can the battery providing power have the lower voltage and the higher voltage at the same time? Either the system has to be oscillating (rapidly switching between the two batteries as each one's voltage reacts to the load), or it has to be showing its analog nature by finding an operating point where the batteries supply enough current each to drop down to the *same* voltage<sup>*</sup>. Probably the latter, but I wouldn't rule out the former without an oscilloscope. Either way, it's not really going to do the thing you wanted.

<sup>*</sup>: well, within a few millivolts anyway. The "ideal diode" still isn't *perfect*, and its voltage drop does still vary a bit with current.